# Return a variable in a Python list with double quotes instead of single

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I am trying to return a variable from a list of strings in double quotes rather than single.

For example, if my list is

```
List = ["A", "B"]
```

if I type `List[0]` the output is `'A'`. Rather, I want `"A"`.  Is there a way to do that? I need this because of an external script that runs in ArcGIS, which accepts only variables within double quotes.

Comment: I am using it with an ArcGIS script, which does not accept a single quote as input, but only double quotes.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  The OP may have misunderstood how Python works, but it's still a fair question.

Comment: Post code showing how you're trying to use it from ArcGIS.

Comment: OP, consider accepting the answer with 50 upvotes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need the output formatted in a particular way, use something like [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> print('"{0}"'.format(List[0]))
"A"
```

The quotes you used to define the strings in the list are forgotten by Python as soon as the line is parsed.  If you want to emit a string with quotes around it, you have to do it yourself.

What you're seeing is the Python interpreter displaying a string representation of the value of the expression.  Specifically, if you type an expression into the interpreter that doesn't evaluate to `None`, it will call [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) on the result in order to generate a string representation that it can display.  For a string, this includes single quotes.

The interactive interpreter is essentially doing something like this each time you type in an expression (called, say, `expr`):

```
result = expr
if result is not None:
    print(repr(result))
```

Note that in my first example, `print` returns `None`, so the interpreter itself doesn't print anything.  Meanwhile, the `print` function outputs the string itself, bypassing the logic above.

Comment: Not sure that is a solution, considering if you remove the print call, it outputs   `'"A"'`

Comment: Thanks, Anyway, I would need to avoid the use of the print function. Rather, I should work on the format of the list itself (if possible), to have the output of "List[0]" to be exactly "A" and not 'A'.

Comment: @umbe1987 there is no difference between the two. It shows `'A'` because that is how the interpreter works, but under the hood they are the exact same string

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes; that's because the interpreter calls `repr` on the result before displaying it.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @umbe1987 Lists don't have "output".  If you want to output a variable with double quotes around it, you have to put them there yourself.  What if you were using it with a different type of script that required back-ticks around strings instead?  Python doesn't support that syntax, so you'd be stuck.

Comment: Thanks to all. The problem was not a matter of double quotes indeed, rather a matter of switched variables in my list. The comment that 'A' and "A" is equal is therefore the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 97):

You could use [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage)

```
>>> import json
>>> List = ["A", "B"]
>>> print json.dumps(List)
["A", "B"]
```

Comment: This produces a string, **not** a list of strings double-quoted

Comment: Note that it also escapes certain characters which might not be what you want.