# To print the strings in list inside double quotes

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I am creating a list of strings inside **double quotes**. I am parsing the **list** to a **dictionary** where the **dictionary** is parsed to a **json file**. the json decoder could not read the strings in list inside **single quotes**.

```
>>> number = ["one", "two"]
>>> mapper = {"numbers" : number}
```

Actual output:

```
>>> print mapper
{'numbers': ['one', 'two']}
```

Desired output:

```
{'numbers': ["one", "two"]}
```

I am using Python 2.7. Please give an solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: but  why.......?

Comment: There is no difference between one quote and double quotes except the representation. If you want to represent your string with double quote search in google for how to format your string in python. Besides, never use a built-in object names as a variable name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a variable in a Python list with double quotes instead of single](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606599/return-a-variable-in-a-python-list-with-double-quotes-instead-of-single)

Comment: @Kasramvd when Python is the consumer, there is no difference. Python is often used for intermediate steps such as data manipulation, and the data then gets exported and consumed by some other service that may have certain constraints. E.g. AWS Redshift requires your arrays to be in a specific format of `["a", "b"]`.

Comment: @Dennis No doubt about it ;).

Answer (score 3):

You can use json like this.

```
import json
print json.dumps(array)
```

Comment: the json.dumps() returns the list as "["one", "two"]" but i need as                ["one", "two"]

Comment: There is no difference in code between double quotes or single quote. In case of printing there is no difference if what you are printing is a string or list.
So what is your problem with returning value of json.dumps()?

Comment: the json decoder could not decode the list. because the list is inside the double quotes

Answer (score 3):

Okay. Wow!  This is gonna be tricky.

First if you want to generate JSON then use the [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).  It's going to be far more reliable and handle many corner cases that you're not yet aware of.

Beyond that the thing you have to understand is that this technique of printing a list, like you're doing it, is not really intended for production output.  It's a convenience for debugging and pedagogy (learning and teaching).

When you print an object in Python then you're seeing its "representation." Under the hood Python calls *`__repr__()`* method as defined by the object's class.  This is also how the object is "represented" in the interpreter (when using Python interactively at the **>>>** prompt).

So, one way you could approach your requirement would be to create your own subclass of Python's *list* type and over-ride the *`__repr__()`* method on that.

Another way would be for you to create your own function (let's call it *`print_list()`*) to print lists in your desired format.

That might look something like:

```
#!python
def print_list(seq):
    '''print a list in our preferred format'''
    print '[%s]' % ', '.join(['"%s"' % x for x in seq])
```

In this case we're defining a function which interpolates a string into the string [...]; and that string is defined by joining a sequence of other strings with commas followed by spaces.  That sequence of other strings is defined by iterating over our arguments (passed through the *seq* parameter to our function) and interpolating each of those into a pair of double quotes.

Note that this function would render *all* objects into double quoted strings.  That will NOT match the built-in representational behavior which only puts quotes (the single quotes that you've objected to) around strings.  The built-in *`__repr__`* for Python lists will not put quotes around numbers, builtin constants like *None* and *True* and *False* and so on.

Specifically this "interpolation" is done, under the hood, by Python's use of another special method  which is called *`__str__()`*.  For simple data types like strings and numbers this is almost the same as what you see when you *print* them.  For instances there are no quotes around the strings or numbers.

In general it's a bad idea to rely on this sort of implementation detail that's exposed by using an object's representation in your production output formatting.

But the key is you have to understand the distinctions between how data is entered into your code (or the interpreter) ... which is called its "literal" form, how it's represented in some sorts of output (debugging, and in the interpreter), and how it's interpolated.  Often the literal form, the representational and string (interpolated) forms will be similar, even identical.  Sometimes the won't be.

**Addendum to address question in comments:**

A variant of the previous function to return the results as a string rather than printing them:

```
#!python
def list_string(seq):
    '''print a list in our preferred format'''
    return '[%s]' % ', '.join(['"%s"' % x for x in seq])
# Usage example:
rendered = list_string([1, 2, 3, 10])
```

In fact it's better to write functions render strings into the desired format rather than calling *print* from within your functions.  In general it's best to call print from has high up (towards your `__main__` suite) as possible.  That makes it easier if you ever have to adapt your program into a module for use with a webUI or a GUI, or to make it work over some custom networking connection or anything of the sort.

Comment: Sorry it works only when i print. But when i write the list, the list itself written inside double quotes

Comment: Amending the answer to explain how you can generate interpolated strings for other purposes.  Basically the same expressions work in assignments as well as in print statements.