# python split problems I need the data output to look different

Tags: python, double-quotes, quoting, single-quotes, output-formatting

```py
s = "ez , dad , tada"
print(s.split(" , "))
```

prints the following:

```py
['ez', 'dad', 'tada']
```

The problems is, I need the output to be with double quotes, not with single quotes, like this:

```py
["ez", "dad", "tada"]
```

Comment: That's just how Python represents lists of strings, when you print them. There's no functional difference between `'` and `"`. And that comma at the end doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want the actual `str` representation to include the double quotes? Like this: `'"ez"'`? What about `[f'"{e}"' for e in s.split(" , ")]`?

Comment: @CrazyChucky they need it in this format the line could be added new here and I don't know how to add it at all

Comment: ...Do you want a list, or do you want a string representing the list?

Comment: @CrazyChucky string representing the list?

Comment: @gmdev   give me complete code thanx

Comment: @Xiddoc ( s = "ez , dad , tada"
print(s.split(" , ")) give mi ['ez', 'dad', 'tada'] ( im search ["ez", "dad", "tada"],  ) this is ok

Comment: If you don't want Pythons representation of a list you have to write your own code.

Comment: @BeastWho check out the answers on this question (this is the comment section, below this are the answers), and if you find any useful ones make sure to upvote them / mark them as valid. If not, then comment on them to see how they can improve their answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a variable in a Python list with double quotes instead of single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606599/return-a-variable-in-a-python-list-with-double-quotes-instead-of-single)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to @fn. for [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606599/return-a-variable-in-a-python-list-with-double-quotes-instead-of-single)

Example:

```
import json

s = "ez , dad , tada"

print(json.dumps(s.split(" , ")))
```

Output:

```
["ez", "dad", "tada"]
```

Comment: Good answer but next time around you can flag the question as a duplicate of the linked post. It helps keeping the site tidy.

Answer (score 1):

You've shown that you used the following code to split up a string into an list:

```py
s = "ez , dad , tada"

split_data = s.split(" , ")
```

Now that you have the data in an list, you can reformat it by using the `.join()` method of a string, to turn the list into a string. According to your example, you want to format the string like `["ez", "dad", "tada"]`, so what you can do is to merge each 2 items with `", "` since that seems to be the seperating string.

```py
separator = '", "'

print('["' + separator.join(split_data) + '"]')
```

Comment: Tip: these are lists. Python *does* have arrays, but [they're different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use).

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I keep mixing them up since I've never actually used an array in Python...