# How do I print a string in double quotes? (NOT PRINT DOUBLE QUOTES)

Tags: python, string, quotes

To be clear, I do not want to print double quotes themselves, I want python to print out my strings in double quotes, instead of single quotes?

for example, if i run the following code in python-

```
print(["this is a string!", "this is another string!"])
```

the result will be

```
['this is a string!', 'this is another string!']
```

i want the output to be in double quotes aswell. How do i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a variable in a Python list with double quotes instead of single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606599/return-a-variable-in-a-python-list-with-double-quotes-instead-of-single)

Comment: Why does it matter? The two representations are equivalent.

Comment: What output type to you want ? You want the string to **contain** double quotes or just when the display way ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.dumps`, that will make a whole string, and the inner string will be double-quoted

```
v = ["this is a string!", "this is another string!"]

# type is list
print(v) # ['this is a string!', 'this is another string!']

# type is string
print(json.dumps(v)) # ["this is a string!", "this is another string!"]
```

Comment: This is essentially the same solution that's in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606599/return-a-variable-in-a-python-list-with-double-quotes-instead-of-single) that this duplicates; I think rather than duplicating the solution to a duplicate question, it would be better to just mark this as a duplicate and move on.